# AWS Copy S3 to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to copy from S3(.csv file) to RDS(MySQL) using Amazon Data pipeline and My error:

> Error copying record
>   Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   Cause: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   Cause: connect timed out

NOTE: I tried RDS TO S3 with the same connection string and it worked! but S3 to RDS does not work not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, It was a permission problem with the EC2 instance spawn by Data Pipeline to run the Copy Activity. You need to make sure that this instance can write into your RDS instance.

Answer (score -1):

I had this error. As said above please check the
`jdbc:mysql://yourrdsdb.cehchrreccbt.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/dbname`